# Facebook API for getting likes count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me how to get my page like count of facebook to show on my website. I have tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<YOUR_PAGE_NAME>/?fields=fan_count&access_token=<EAAUo6u... - YOU_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

but not able to get data. Error shows :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

You can either use a Page Access Token of your Page, or you need to go through review in order to get access with an App or User Access Token.